# My camera is lost in my workspace and I cant find it

Tags: interface, camera

I have some how lost my blender model, I know its thwart because I press Numpad+0 and my camera setup shows my model but when I return to the regular camera all i see is the grid lines. I have tried Shift+C and it does nothing

Comment: what you mean by regular camera is the normal 3D view? If you want to bring back some elements to the center of your scene, you can select them and press alt G. If you want to keep the same organization, maybe parent them all to an empty, select the empty and press alt G, press shift C to come back to the center of the scene, then deparent the object with alt P > Clear and Keep Transformation?

Answer (score 1):

Select your camera in the outliner then put your mouse inside any 3d view and press <kbd>Numpad .</kbd> (period key on the number keypad).

Answer (score 0):

You can go out of the camera view just by rotating the view and you wont ever come back to that lost far away place.